# Package a phonegap project to Windows

Tags: cordova

I am looking for a way to package a Phonegap project in a Windows Package/Executable so users have the same experience in all platforms, or for a way to deliver the same content without using an emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to package your own browser along with the PhoneGap package so that you can be sure of a consistent experience. You might want to look at [Chromium Embedded](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) which is small and will allow you to easily build an executable that hosts your PhoneGap project.

To create the executable, look at the available bindings for CEF such as CEFSharp that would allow you to build your 'bootstrap' application using .NET

Note that some of the PhoneGap specific APIs will not work in a desktop browser and might require some code changes.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, and link.

Comment: If you think this answer is correct, can you mark it as such?